# Implementing generic and extension ObservableCollection method with custom data model in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, extension-methods, observablecollection

I have a model class MessageModel in my MVVM app which contains below constructors:

```
public class MessageModel
{
        // Private fields here 

        public MessageModel()
        {
        }

        public MessageModel(MessageType msgType, DateTime dateTime, string strSource, string strText)
        {
            this._type = msgType;
            this._dateTime = dateTime;
            this._source = strSource;
            this._text = strText;
        }

        // Public properties here
}
```

In view model I have below declaration:

```
ObservableCollection<MessageModel> myMessages = new ObservableCollection<MessageModel>();
```

Now I need to add items to this collection always at the first position (at the beginning), so I do:

```
myMessages.Insert(0, new MessageModel() { 
                             // values here 
                         });
```

As I do if often I want to implement an extension method for collection like this (It does not compile):

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static void Insert<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, MessageType messageType, IParticipant sender, string strText)  where T : MessageModel
    {
        collection.Insert(0, new T()
        {
            MessageType = messageType,
            MessageDateTime = DateTime.Now,
            MessageSource = sender.ParticipantName,
            MessageText = strText
        });
    }
}
```

Then I can do:

```
myMessages.Insert(messageType, sender, text);
```

Is that possible? If so, how?

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and NET Framework 3.5

Comment: you are missing `, new()` after `where T : MessageModel`

Comment: @yolosora now when I call myMessages.Insert(messageType, sender, text) an error is thrown. Compiler does not recognize Insert as an extension method.

Comment: Oh my God!!!!! I was missing the namespace of the class where the extension method is. Importing namespace "using MyNamespaceWhereExtensionMethodIs" in the class where I call the method myMessages.Insert is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you should add `new()` to allow using constructor in your extension method

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static void Insert<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, MessageType messageType, IParticipant sender, string strText)  where T : MessageModel, new()
    {
        collection.Insert(0, new T()
        {
            MessageType = messageType,
            MessageDateTime = DateTime.Now,
            MessageSource = sender.ParticipantName,
            MessageText = strText
        });
    }
}
```

Then you should use your extension method like this:

```
myMessages.Insert<MessageModel>(messageType, sender, text);
```

Comment: Yes, it is working. I forgot to import the namespace from where I call the extension method. Thx.